# Show div if cookie is set

Tags: javascript

I'm using js-cookie to set a cookie. I've got a div which is set to `display: none;` and if the cookie is set I want to change it to `display:block;` .

The HTML:

```
<div id="cookie-hide">
  <p>test</p>
 </div>
```

The CSS:

```
<style>
#cookie-hide {display: none;}
</style>
```

This is the JS:

```
<script>
function checkCookie() {
    var user= Cookies.get('video')
    if (user != "") {
      document.getElementById("cookie-hide").style.display = "block";
    }
}

Cookies.set('video', 'play');
</script>
```

I can see in chrome that the cookie has been set but the div still doesn't display. Any ideas what's wrong with the code?

Comment: You need to put that script below the actual HTML - there is a canonical about it

Comment: @TakitIsy JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion

Comment: change your condition `user != ""` to `user`

Comment: You have not invoked `checkCookie`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, so why bother putting them after the expressions ?

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine. You are not calling the function anywhere.

```
function checkCookie() {
    var user= Cookies.get('video')
    if (user != "") {
        document.getElementById("cookie-hide").style.display = "block";
    }
}

Cookies.set('video', 'play');

checkCookie();         // <----- This line.
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/u1x030b4/

Answer (score 0):

Do it as:

```
if (user == "") {
var x = document.getElementById("cookie-hide");
x.style.display = "block";
}
```

This should work